Apollo client completely disable caching, or fix caching issue
So we have this problem with Apollo client. Our stack if following: PayloadCMS graphQL API and Next.js 14 with Apollo client.
The problem is following when data are changed on the PayloadCMS, the Next website data are not updated. Sometimes force reload fixes the problem (which is not solution), and even stranger for me is that only sometimes.
I feel like we tried all possible configuration that we could to fix it. Still without success. The best solution would be disable caching permanently and always fetch newest data from server.
Apollo client config:
import { HttpLink } from "@apollo/client";
import {
  registerApolloClient,
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
} from "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support";
export const { getClient } = registerApolloClient(() => {
  return new ApolloClient({
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ADMIN_BASE_URI}/api/graphql`,
    }),
    defaultOptions: {
      query: {
        fetchPolicy: "network-only",
      },
    },
    ssrMode: true,
    ssrForceFetchDelay: 1,
    cache: new InMemoryCache({
      resultCaching: false,
    }),
  });
});


Fetching the data using Postman is always fine, so I assumed the problem is on the client side.

Have you tried disabling the Next.js fetch cache? Ypu definitely don't need ssrMode, ssrForceFetchDelay or resultCaching  options, please remove those.

@phry Unfortunately it didn't work. Do you maybe have another idea how to solve the issue?

I think you need to describe more what you expect here. Should it update while a user is on the page? Only on refresh? Are you doing additional things like clearing data out of the next.js fetch cache? If yes, how?

I would like to not use any cache at all, application wide. I expect Next.js to fetch new data on every request made. I don't need any client side fetching.

Next.js per default caches any request you make with fetch during SSR and can serve that old request to your users hours later. You need to configure that behaviour, or actively disable it. If you have not actively disabled it, that's probably your problem here.
